# google cloud messaging and push notification to device?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i need to know and understand what is the concept used by google cloud messaging to push notification to the device.
I know that GCM check every some minute if there are new messages awaiting, if yes google push this message to android app, my question is how google push this message to the specific android app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained in the Google documentation

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#s2s

This is how these components interact:

- Google-provided **GCM Connection Servers** take messages from
  a 3rd-party app server and send these messages to a
  GCM-enabled client app (the "client app").
  Currently Google provides connection servers for HTTP
  and XMPP.
- The **3rd-Party App Server** is a component that you
  implement to work with your chosen GCM connection server(s). App servers send
  messages to a GCM connection server; the connection server enqueues and stores the
  message, and then sends it to the client app.
  For more information, see Implementing GCM Server.
- The **Client App** is a GCM-enabled client app.
  To receive GCM messages, this app must register with GCM and get a
  registration ID. If you are using the XMPP (CCS) connection
  server, the client app can send "upstream" messages back to the 3rd-party app server.
  For more information on how to implement the client app, see
  the documentation for your platform.

Comment: so the GCM connection server is a server the create http connection (or xmpp) with the specific device to send message to it, my question is how this http connection is created , and how i can create a similar http connection to connect to the android device?

Comment: I don't know exactly. When you create an android app, you register a listener for push notifications. Android handles the rest of the work. Are you trying to send push message directly to the app?

Comment: Im am not trying to send message directly to app as im trying to create a simulator for google cloud messaging, but seems like it is not possible at all, we must give in to use google cloud messaging to receive notification, unless i create an android app that check the web service every some minutes and this web service return if there are new messages , if yes then i display it

Answer (score -1):

At the time of registration of app with gcm an id saved on gcm server and returned to app as well that gcmRegistrationId saved on app server and when anyone want to send push notification to a specific id then message sends to gcm server with that gcmRegistrationId and by comparing that id gcm sends that message to a particular client.